# Proving $E(\hat s^2)=V(\bar x)$ for finite population

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

Population is $X_1,X_2,...,X_N$ with large but finite $N$. Sampling indicator $Z_i \in(0,1)~ \forall i$ , such that $\sum^N _{i=1}Z_i=n$ and $Pr(Z_i=1)=\frac {n}{N}$.

Sample mean in this case is $\bar x=\frac{1}{n}\sum^N _{i=1}Z_iX_i$, where $E(\bar x)=\bar X$.

Variance of the estimator is $V(\bar x)=(1-\frac {n}{N})\frac {S^2}{n}$, where $S^2=\sum^N _{i=1}(X_i-\bar X)^2/(N-1)$ is the population variance.

Sample variance is $\hat s^2=(1-\frac {n}{N})\frac {s^2}{n}$, where $s^2=\sum^N _{i=1}Z_i(X_i-\bar x)^2/(n-1)$.

I want to show that $E(\hat s^2)=V(\bar x)$, i.e.,the sample variance is an unbiased estimator. Note that $Z_i$ is the only random variable here, so does $\bar x$, because $\bar x$ consists $Z_i$.

I derived the following but do not know how to proceed foward, could someone help me with this please? Thanks!

My attempt:

\begin{align}
E(\hat s^2) &= \frac {1-\frac {n}{N}}{n(n-1)}E\bigl[ \sum^N_{i=1}Z_i(X_i-\bar x)^2 \bigr] \\
&=\frac {1-\frac {n}{N}}{n(n-1)} E\Bigl[ \sum^N_{i=1} Z_i \cdot \bigl( X_i -\bar X) + (\bar X-\bar x) \bigr)^2 \Bigr] \\
&= \frac {1-\frac {n}{N}}{n(n-1)}E\Bigl[\sum^N_{i=1} Z_i \cdot \bigl( (X_i-\bar X)^2+2(X_i-\bar X)(\bar X-\bar x)+(\bar X-\bar x)^2 \bigr) \Bigr] 
\end{align}

I know that

$$E[\sum^N_{i=1}Z_i(X_i-\bar X)^2]=\sum^N_{i=1}E(Z_i)(X_i-\bar X)^2=\sum^N_{i=1}Pr(Z_i=1)(X_i-\bar X)^2=\frac{n}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}(X_i-\bar X)^2$$

How should I deal with the latter terms of $2(X_i-\bar X)(\bar X-\bar x)+(\bar X-\bar x)^2$? Any comment would be helpful!

Comment: $E(\bar X-\bar x)^2=E(\bar x -E(\bar x))^2=Var(\bar x)$
 and

$\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \bar{X})= \sum (X_i )- N \bar{X} = N \bar{X} - N \bar{X}=0$

Comment: @papasmurfete How does this help? You didn't account for the multiplication with $Z_i$.

Comment: $E[2\sum^N_{i=1}Z_i(X_i-\bar X)(\bar X-\bar x)+\sum^N_{i=1}Z_i(\bar X-\bar x)^2]=E[2(\sum^N_{i=1}Z_iX_i-n\bar X)(\bar X-\bar x)+n(\bar X-\bar x)^2]=E[2(n \bar x-n\bar X)(\bar X-\bar x)+(\bar X-\bar x)^2]=E[-2n(\bar X-\bar x)^2+(\bar X-\bar x)^2]=E[-n(\bar X-\bar x)^2]$

Comment: @D.OUI there are many ways to prove this, if after understanding papasmurfete's comment you feel like seeing a different presentation, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common anchoring $X_i - \bar x = (X_i - \bar X) + (\bar X - \bar x)~$ is very meaningful and can be seen to be useful as per the [comments by papasmurfete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949609/proving-e-hat-s2-v-bar-x#comment6092800_2949609). Nonetheless, in this case we can arguably have a simpler algebraic derivation without that anchoring.

Back to the beginning, we expand the square into the usual 3-parts but only bring the expectation inside the summation for the first term.

\begin{align}
\frac{ n(n-1) }{1 - \frac{n}N } E(\hat s^2) &= \color{blue}{ \sum^N_{i=1} E \Bigr[ Z_i X_i^2 \Bigr] } - 2 E \Bigl[ \sum^N_{i=1} Z_i X_i \bar x \Bigr] + E \Bigl[ \sum^N_{i=1} Z_i \bar x^2 \Bigr]  \\
&= \color{blue}{ \sum^N_{i=1} X_i^2 E \Bigr[ Z_i \Bigr] } - 2 E \Bigl[ \bar x \sum^N_{i=1} Z_i X_i \Bigr] +  E \Bigl[ \bar x^2 \sum^N_{i=1} Z_i \Bigr] \\
&= \color{blue}{ \frac{n}N \sum^N_{i=1} X_i^2} - 2 E \Bigl[ \bar x \cdot n \bar x \Bigr] + E \Bigl[ \bar x^2 \cdot n \Bigr] \\
&= \frac{n}N \sum^N_{i=1} X_i^2 - n E \Bigl[ \bar x^2 \Bigr]
\end{align}
Hopefully each step above is self-explanatory. Now, the common factor $n$ cancels on two sides of the equation, and we know the second moment is the variance plus the square of mean.

\begin{align}
\frac{ n-1 }{1 - \frac{n}N } E(\hat s^2) &= \frac1N \sum^N_{i=1} X_i^2 -  \left( V( \bar x^2 ) + E[\bar x]^2 \right) \\
&= \frac1N \sum^N_{i=1} X_i^2 - V( \bar x^2 ) - \bar X^2  \\
&= \frac1N \left( \sum^N_{i=1} X_i^2 - N \bar X^2  \right) - V( \bar x^2 ) \\
&= \frac1N  \sum^N_{i=1} (X_i - \bar X)^2 - V( \bar x^2 ) \\
&= \frac1N \frac{ n (N - 1) }{1 - \frac{n}N } V( \bar x^2 ) - V( \bar x^2 ) 
\end{align}
The coefficient for $V( \bar x^2 )$ on the right hand side is shown to be
$$ \frac{ n (N - 1) }{N - n} - 1 = \frac{ n N - n - (N - n)}{N - n} = \frac{ (n-1)N }{ N - n} = \frac{ n - 1}{ 1 - \frac{n}N }~,$$
the same as that for $E(\hat s^2)$ on the left hand side. This proves $E(\hat s^2) = V( \bar x^2 )$

---

Besides the algebraic manipulation similar to the above, a classic proof can be seen in **chapter 2** of a [well-known old text by Cochran](https://books.google.com.tw/books/about/Sampling_Techniques_3Rd_Edition.html?id=xbNn41DUrNwC). In particular, if you can get a copy, the author establishes a hierarchy of relations of great importance from **Theorem 2.1** going to **Theorem 2.4** while emphasizing the concepts instead of the algebra.

This might not be what you started out having in mind, but it provides a different flavor to say the least.